# Moq testing void method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

Hi I am new to Moq testing and having hard time to do a simple assertion. 
I am using an interface

```
 public interface IAdd
 {
     void add(int a, int b);
 }
```

Moq for the `IAdd` interface is:

```
  Mock<IAdd> mockadd = new Mock<IAdd>();
  mockadd.Setup(x => x.add(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>()).callback((int a, int b) => { a+b;});
  IAdd testing = mockadd.Object;
```

Since the `add` method is void, it doesn't return any value to Assert with. How can I assert this setup?

Comment: What are you trying to test?

Comment: I am trying to test that add method but it doesn't have any return type. If it had int as return type, I would be testing Assert.AreEqual(mockadd.add(2,2), 4); But without return type how do I test the add method.

Comment: **1.** It makes no sense to test an interface (or a mock implementation). **2.** If you have a class that computes something, you may want to make the result available somehow (either via return value or some property on that object)

Comment: Strange, Add doesn't return anything ??? Need to look for a better method name.

Answer (score 23):

Why mocking is used? It used for verifying that SUT (system under test) interacts correctly with its dependencies (which should be mocked). Correct interaction means calling correct dependency members with correct parameters.

You should **never assert on value returned by mock**. That is dummy value which has no relation to production code. The only value you should assert on is a value returned by SUT. SUT is the only thing you should write assertions for.

Also you should **never test interfaces**. Because there is nothing to test. Interface is just a API description. It has no implementation. So, stop and think about what code are you testing here? Is this is a real code, which executed in your application?

So, you should mock `IAdd` interface only for testing object which uses `IAdd` interface.

Comment: Hi Sergey, I'm new on this mock tests. I would like to avoid the void method to execute, the method updates the database, is theer a better way of doing so?

Answer (score 22):

Better to provide more context, but typically it used like this:

```
var mockAdd = new Mock<IAdd>();
mockAdd.Setup(x => x.Add(1, 2)).Verifiable();

//do something here what is using mockAdd.Add

mockAdd.VerifyAll();
```

Comment: Pavel, can you explain a little more about //do something here what is using mockAdd.Add. I am stuck on a similar problem and not sure what to add to "//do something here what is using mockAdd.Add"

Comment: would be nice to add some explanation to the commented out part @PavelBakshy