# MS Test for Void Methods

Tags: c#, sql, unit-testing, mstest

I have a **void** method, which i need to unit test, can some one please help me how to do it

```
[TestMethod()]
public void ProcessProductFeedTest()
{
    // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
    ProductDataServiceProvider target = new ProductDataServiceProvider();

    target.ProcessProductFeed();
    Assert.Inconclusive("A method that does not return a value cannot be verified.");
}
```

in the above code ProcessProductFeed() is a void method which gets some data from SQL server DB and publish to TIBCO, how can i write a unit test case for the same

Answer (score 3):

Well, you should test that the data is published to TIBCO, basically.

For any method, your tests should either test that the value returned is correct if the primary purpose is to compute something, or that the appropriate side-effects have occurred if that's the primary purpose of the method. (You then test the error conditions as well, of course.)

Without knowing anything about either TIBCO or your architecture, I can't really comment on how you go about testing the publishing part. I would personally separate out the three stages of reading, processing and publishing - then each part can be tested in isolation from the others.

Comment: Emphasis should be made on testing each component in isolation. Testing the entire thing in one go is IMHO very dangerous as it means that logic errors in the business can be masked by the other layers.

Comment: Testing all the components together would be an integration test not a unit test.

Comment: @Romoku I'm aware but people often forget that and do things like [testing moq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15062403/moq-testing-void-method?rq=1)

Answer (score 3):

Abstract persistence and TIBCO communication from your class. E.g. you can use some repository interface for communication with SQL server :

```
public interface IProductsRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Product> GetSomeProducts();
    // other members
}
```

And some gateway for communcation with TIBCO (I named it Stock, but you should provide business specific names):

```
public interface IStockGateway
{
    void DoSomethingWithProducts(IEnumerable<Product> products);
    // other members
}
```

Then make your class depend on these abstractions. You will be able to mock them and verify class behavior:

```
public class ProductDataServiceProvider
{
     private IProductsRepository _productRepository;
     private IStockGateway _stockGateway;

     // inject implementations
     public ProductDataServiceProvider(
         IProductRepository productRepository,
         IStockGateway stockGateway)
     {
         _productRepository = productRepository;
         _stockGateway = stockGateway; 
     }

     public void ProcessProductFeed()
     {
          // use repository and gateway
     }
}
```

Now, back to test. What are responsibilities of your provider - get some products from product repository (implementation of this repository will load products from SQL database) and pass them to gateway (implementation of gateway will publish products to TIBCO). Here is test which uses [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart) library:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ShouldPassSomeProjectToStock()
{
    // Arrange
    var products = new List<Product>() { }; // create some products
    var mockRepository = new Mock<IProductRepository>();
    mockRepository.Setup(r => r.GetSomeProducts()).Returns(products);

    var mockGateway = new Mock<IStockGateway>();
    mockGateway.Setup(g => g.DoSomethingWithProducts(products));

    var provider = new ProductDataServiceProvider(mockRepository.Object, 
                                                  ockGateway.Object);
    // Act
    provider.ProcessProductFeed();
    // Assert
    mockRepository.VerifyAll(); // verify products retrieved from repository
    mockGateway.VerifyAll(); // verify products passed to gateway
}
```

Comment: @CSharped thanks :) One more thing - there is two types of testing - state-based testing, which verifies state of system after exercising it (i.e. public properties, returned results), and interaction-based testing, which verifies how your object communicates with its dependencies. I recommend you to read Fowler's article [Mocks Aren't Stubs](http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html) to understand these different approaches better

Comment: @CSharped also keep in mind, that tests should be [FIRST](http://pragprog.com/magazines/2012-01/unit-tests-are-first) which means you should not use real database or TIBCO when unit-testing provider